# Probability that $3$ non - negative numbers sum up to $1$ and each are less than $m$ or two are greater than $m$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

## Problem:

A random triplet is taken from the set of non - negative real numbers satisfying $x+y+z=1$. I am intrigued to find the probability of:

1. $x,y,z\leq m $ where $\frac{1}{3}\leq m\leq \frac{1}{2}$ or
2. Two of $x,y,z$ are greater than or equal to $m$ where $\frac{1}{3}\leq m \leq\frac{1}{2}$

## My attempt:

Please refer to the picture, triangle $ABC$ is equilateral triangle with sides $1$

1. $x\vec{A}+y\vec{B}+z\vec{C}$ consists of all points inside triangle $ABC$
2. $x\vec{A}+y\vec{B}+z\vec{C}$ with $x,y,z\leq m$ consists of all points inside triangle with sides $3m-1$. Denoted by $S$
3. $x\vec{A}+y\vec{B}+z\vec{C}$ with two of $x,y,z$ greater than or equal to $m$ consists of all points inside three triangles with sides $1-2m$. Denoted by $P,Q,R$

Thus the probability are given by ratio of triangles area: $(3m-1)^{2}+3(1-2m)^{2}$

[image: Sketch1]

Could You guys please check this solution and drop Your own solutions too. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what $A,B,C$ are?

Comment: @h-squared sorry i missed Your comment, they are position vector of the triangle vertices